# Have a background color set up on half of a button using gradient property with curved rounded edges

Tags: html, css, gradient

I have a requirement to have a button which should display two colors on it. I was able to achieve mix up the colors to a certain level using gradient property  but not able to produce the exact one. I want the gradient color set inside a button have curved and rounded edges.Below is my code,

HTML

```
<button class='triangle'>
  Linear Check 
</button>
```

CSS

```
.triangle{
  padding:20px;
  border:none;
  --g:red 135deg,yellow 0; /* the coloration */
  --p:30%;/* the position */
  background:
    conic-gradient(from -180deg at 50% var(--p)             ,var(--g)) top,
    conic-gradient(from -135deg at 50% calc(100% - var(--p)),var(--g)) bottom;
  background-size:100% 51%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}[enter image description here][1]
```

Using the below code in was able to achieve the below one,

But my actual requirement is to have the edges of the gradient color(blue) to be rounded rather than have sharp steep edges. So the requirement it would look similar like the below,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPvru.png)

As in the image i want the edges to be curved and rounded.Can this be achieved using the Gradient properties.Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, please use a Stacksnippet `<>` or `Ctrl+M` the next time you post code. That stacksnippet is 
runnable and show the output of your code directly. Also you can include images directly instead 
of just linking them. I edited your question and did the formatting for you.

Comment: can you use pseudo elements? (::after, ::before)

Comment: @pan is it possible to achieve using pseudo elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doable with multiple background layer:

```css
.triangle{
  --d:10px; /* distance from top */
  --r:10px; /* radius of circle */
  --c:red;
  padding:20px;
  border:none;
  background:
    linear-gradient(var(--c) 0 0) left/calc(50% + var(--r)) calc(100% - 2*var(--d) - 2*var(--r)),
    linear-gradient(var(--c) 0 0) left/50% calc(100% - 2*var(--d)),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,var(--c) 98%,#0000 ) left 50% top    var(--d)/calc(var(--r)*2) calc(var(--r)*2),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,var(--c) 98%,#0000 ) left 50% bottom var(--d)/calc(var(--r)*2) calc(var(--r)*2),
     yellow;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<button class='triangle'>
  Linear Check 
</button>

<button class='triangle' style="--d:5px">
  Linear Check 
</button>

<button class='triangle' style="--d:5px;--r:20px">
  Linear Check 
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using pseudo elements you can use these styles to achieve what you mentioned:

```css
.triangle{
    padding:20px;
    border:none;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.triangle::after {
    content: "";
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: -10%;
    width: 25%;
    height: 80%;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>btn gradient</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button class='triangle'>
    Linear Check 
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

You can change the values if you need.

Comment: Thanks for the response .This will work in getting same design. But my objective here is  to achieve  this using the gradient properties(linear,radial or conical).

Comment: @devangular I tried using radial gradient but the result was not **exactly** similar to the shape that you put in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest way to solve it, is using div instead of button.
So:

1. Replace the button element with div

```html
<div class="triangle">Click me</div>
```

2. tweak the CSS rules of the div to match your need + add button feeling to the div

```css
.triangle{
  /* your CSS rules from your question... */
  
 /* Give the button the wanted radius here */
    border-radius: 15px;
}

/* Give the div button effect when hover*/
.triangle:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px -5px;
    transform: scale(1.03);
}

/* Give the div button effect when click */
.triangle:active {
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px;
    transform scale(.98);
}
```